# get label value on button clicked from tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, tableview

I want to get value of label and on button click without using this function

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
...
}
```

I want to pass that label's value to next view controller using prepareforsegue()

Comment: Your button is inside cell? also add the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Yes, its inside the cell. I have used cellForRowAtIndexPath to fill the label. Now i want to get the label and pass it to other ViewController on click Button which is also inside the Cell.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

you have a cell with a UIButton and a UILabel, let's say your cell class is MyTableViewCell, your button named myButton and your label named myLabel

in cellForRowAtIndexPath set target for the button

```
 cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cellButtonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

then in your tableView view controller add this function

```
func cellButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    //button (sender) superview is the contentView of the cell (not the cell itself)
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! MyTableViewCell
    print(cell.myLabel.text!)
}
```

Comment: if all what you want is the string in the data source array that filled the label, i can give you another answer